# In XL using VBA, is there a simple way to step through every table in a workbook and set every cell value to 0?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an XL workbook that has multiple tables on multiple sheets. As I go along, I've been adding to and modifying a subroutine that can zeroise the tables. This is time consuming (and error-prone), especially as I keep having to modify my tables at the whim of my beloved users. Can anyone come up with a routine that will just find each table and zeroise it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems. Also, suggest you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better help you with your code.

Comment: You can refer to all the cells in a table using its `DataBodyRange`. Simply iterate through each `ListObject` in each `Worksheet` and set its `DataBodyRange.Value` to 0 (e.g. tbl.DataBodyRange.Value = 0`).   If you have any issues post your code and I'll be happy to get it working for you.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. This works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop through each table in your workbook and set all values to 0

```
Public Sub PopulateTables()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
            tbl.DataBodyRange.Value2 = 0
        Next tbl
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thanks.